# How to solve the following second order differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, eigenfunctions

What are the numerical or analytical solution methods (preferably analytical) for solving following differential equation to find $A_n(t)$? and how to solve it?

$$B.A_n''(t)+(\frac{n\pi}{l})^4A_n(t)$$ $$+C\sum_{i=1}^N\bigg[\bigg(\frac{2}{l}\sin(\frac{i\pi vt}{l})\sin(\frac{n\pi vt}{l})\bigg)\bigg(1+\frac{i\pi}{l}A_i'(t)+v'\frac{i\pi}{l}A_i(t)+(\frac{i\pi}{l})^2A_i(t)+G(t)\bigg)\bigg]=F_n(t)$$
where $B,C,l$ are constants, 
$v(t)$ is velocity, 
$F_n(t)$ and $G(t)$ are functions of $t$.

Is there anybody who has idea to solve?

Comment: You can't use the same index outside and inside a summation.

Comment: Sorry, I edited.

Comment: Where is the $j$? And is the velocity a function of time as well? (So v’ would be $dv/dt$)

Comment: I edited. Do you have any idea for solving?

Comment: What is the $i$ outside the summation in the second term, and is there a relationship between $n$ and $N$? Also $A'$ and $v'A$ have different dimensions so are these terms right?

Comment: Thank you user121049. It is $n$ outside the summation in the second term. I think we will take limit $n, N\rightarrow\infty$ in the next step. I am not sure whether $A'$ and $v'A$ have different dimensions or not.

Comment: Or we will assume that $n$ and $N$ are equal to each other in the next step.